# How to convert .docx to .doc using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, .doc, document-conversion

I need to know how to convert `.docx` to `.doc` using `apache poi`, maybe using `XWPFDocument` ,`HWPFDocument` classes, if not achievable please provide alternative solutions.

Comment: Both formats are microsoft specific. What value do you get by using poi?  The conversion may be lossy, it is better done via ms tools.

Comment: how can i do this using ms tools, any documentation, useful links ?

Comment: Glad this is done.  I am removing poi tag. You may write your solution as an answer.  It is going to help lot of folks.

Comment: exactly, i will need some time, to put a detailed solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LibreOffice, driven via JODConverter.

Comment: That's what i'm trying right now, but i have problems setting OpenOffice 4 to run as a service on windows, do you have any documentation, useful links ?

Comment: it's working now like a charm, if anyone needs assistance on this, i'am keen to help.

Comment: how do you solve this? I'm looking now for solve the same problem