# How to convert doc to docx using Tika or POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-tika

How to convert a .doc file to .docx using apache Tika or with apache POI? I am stuck in converting the document to docx format.

Comment: Did you have a look at [JODConverter](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/)? SO had a similar question [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484225/how-to-convert-docx-to-doc-using-apache-poi).

Comment: I don't want to use JOD converter. My requirement holds with POI or Tika.

Comment: In that case, unless your documents are very simple, you'll need to write a fair bit of code (so each feature of interest to you is implemented for legacy binary doc in HWPF, and can be written to XWPF (docx))

Comment: @JasonPlutext My Question is that how to do it?

Comment: Well, https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/Doc.java is simple HWPF to docx4j; since that is ASLv2 code, you can adapt/extend it to convert to XWPF instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert .docx to .doc using apache poi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484225/how-to-convert-docx-to-doc-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

I use `aspose words` to convert `.doc` to `.docx`.

```
Document doc = new Document(filePath);
doc.save(descFilePath);
```

Very convenient, ust two lines.